# Angular2-material: Dynamically set styling on md-tab?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've noticed that some of the material design components are tricky to style.
At the moment, I'm trying to dynamically set styling on an md-tab.
Tabs can be set as active or archived in my application, and I simply want to visually indicate this by setting the text of the tab header to italic, and give it a different text color.

I have tried setting the css class to 'item-archived' or 'item-active' depending on the tab.archived property, but all of the HTML is rewritten when the component is initialized, removing the class I just set.

I've googled around for a while, but couldn't really come up with a conclusive answer on how best to do this.
The very few examples I did find all use predefined static styles instead of having logic added into the equation.

I'm assuming there is no elegant way to do this, and a sort of workaround is required?

My code (simplified):

```
<md-tab-group class="tab-container">
<md-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" label="{{tab.name}}" class="{{ tab.archive && 'item-archived' || 'item-active' }}">
    ...
</md-tab>
```

I would think this shouldn't be too difficult to do, right? Can anyone point me towards a clean solution?

Comment: You should be using ngStyle instead

Comment: I realize ngStyle is the best way to do this in most cases, but it doesn't work in this case. "Can't bind to 'ng-style' since it isn't a known property of 'md-tab'."

Answer (score 1):

I used a workaround based on the fact that the `ng-reflect-active` attribute is set to `true` when the tab is selected and added a css style on that:

```
[ng-reflect-active=true]{
  color:blue;
}
```

It works for now with angular-material 2.0.0-beta.3

**Update**: Just a heads up; this will not work when you build your app for production. These ng-reflect classes is added when angular is in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting classes dynamically using the below code

```
<nav md-tab-nav-bar aria-label="">
          <a md-tab-link [ngClass]="{'item-active' : activeLinkIndex == i}"
             *ngFor="let routeLink of routeLinks; let i = index"
             [routerLink]="routeLink.link"
             [active]="activeLinkIndex === i"
             (click)="activeLinkIndex = i">
            {{routeLink.label}}
          </a>
        </nav>
```

My style class contains

```
.item-active{
  color:blue !important;
}
```

This applies only when the important attribute is set to the property, and fails for other cases.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/k0XFeD4CkHLTEtUOmGCI?p=preview)**